# prove that $\Lambda(S)$ is closed for every closed set $S \subset X$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, solution-verification, closed-graph

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and let $\Lambda : X \to Y$ be a bounded linear operator. Is it true that if $\Lambda$ is surjective and hence open, then $\Lambda(S)$ is closed for every closed set $S \subset X$ ?

$\textbf{Is the following a correct answer? if yes I wondered why we need the openness of $\Lambda$?}$

We have to show that  any sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ in $\mathcal{G}(\Lambda (S)) = \{(x,y) : x\in S \ \ \& \ \ \ \Lambda x=y \in Y\}$ converges to a point $(x,y)$ in $\mathcal{G}(\Lambda (S))$.

Since $S$ is a closed subset of $X$, it is complete. So let's take any cauchy sequence $(x_n, \Lambda x_n)$ in $\mathcal{G}(\Lambda (S))$. Since $S\times Y$ is Banach, and $\Lambda$ is surjective we have that $(x_n, \Lambda x_n) \to (x,y)$ in $S\times Y$ for some $y$. It remains to show that $\Lambda x=y$.

We have that by completeness of $S$, that $x_n \to x$ in $S$, and by the continuity of $\Lambda$, $\Lambda x_n \to \Lambda x$,  also we have that by definition of convergence $\Lambda x_n \to y$. So choose $N$ s.t. for all $n\geq N$, $\|\Lambda x_n - \Lambda x\|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\|\Lambda x_n - y\|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. So

$$\|\Lambda x-y\|\le\|\Lambda x_n - \Lambda x\|+\|\Lambda x_n - y\|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$

so since $\mathcal{G}(\Lambda (S))$ is closed for any point in $S$,  then $\Lambda (S)$ is also closed.

Comment: How does closedness of $\mathcal G(\Lambda(S))$ imply closedness of $\Lambda (S)$?

Comment: so may be I got it wrong. I thought that when  the graph is closed then the image of the operator as is part of the graph is also closed.  Can you provide me an example (also is possible geometrically) that this is no always true?

Comment: That is what I have done in my answer. $\mathcal G(\Lambda(S))$ is closed in that example but $\Lambda (S)$ is not closed.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=\mathbb  R^{2}$ and $Y=\mathbb R$. Let $\Lambda (x,y)=x$ and $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{2}: xy=1\}$. Then the hypothesis is satisfied and $\Lambda (S)=\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ which is not closed.

Comment: @stat It appears that you are not happy with the answer. Do you want more details?